# get certain text from outlook email body using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following code to retrieve the company name from my email body. so for instance if I have

```
Company name: Hewden
```

then I want to get `'Hewden'`

underneath company name in my email body I also have the following:

```
company number: 123
company status: live

kind regards,

automated email
```

I am using the following code to try and retrieve just the company name 'Hewden' without any of the preceding or after text.

i am getting an invalid procedure call or argument error, on the line `b4 = olkmsgt.Body`

and am not sure why, can someone please show me how to amend this to get it to do what i want.

thanks

```
Dim b4 As String
                        b4 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
        indexOfNameb = InStr(1, b4, "Company Name: ")

    Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
        indexOfNamec = InStr(1, b4, "Company number: ")

    Dim finalStringb As String

        finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)
        Dim LResult36 As String
        LResult36 = Replace(finalStringb, "Company Name: ", "")

       excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 1) = LResult36
```

Comment: What is olkMsg here?

Comment: i have set olkmsg as an object like so Dim olkMsg As Object, _

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the object / item olkMsg is Outlook MailItem. It may be invitation, task etc. which has no body property.

```
if TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" then
b4 = olkMsg.Body
...
```

Edit (Answer to comment):
InStr() is Case Sensitive. "Company name: " is not "Company Name: "
Try to put all the strings to UCases to get rid of the case sensitivness:

```
If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b4 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
        indexOfNameb = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company name: "))

    Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
        indexOfNamec = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company number: "))

    Dim finalStringb As String

        finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)
        Dim LResult36 As String
        LResult36 = Replace(finalStringb, "Company Name: ", "")

       excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 1) = LResult36
End If
```

Comment: ok the error is now no longer showing up on the b4 = olkMsg.Body line but instead is no saying invalid procedure on this line: finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)

Comment: for some reason if I get rid of b4 = olkMsg.Body and replace it with text like "Blah blah blah Company Name: Test blah blah blhab" then it works fine, for some reason its not liking the b4 = olkMgsg.body line

Comment: thanks I have copied and pasted your code exactly but this still produces the invalid procedure argument error for the line: finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)